# appearance phrase question

Tags: single-word-requests

My student wrote in his essay

> it gives her face a peculiar charm?

I tried all the dictionaries at hand (hard-copy and electronic ones) but did not find a definite answer whether this phrase sounds English. Could you please help me?

Comment: What does it sound like if it's not English? English is a flexible and vivid language that isn't limited to set phrases that are always found in a reference source.

Comment: @Jim German is even more flexible. You can string a lot of words together and it will still be grammatically correct. Can't do this in English, but I just wanted to say it :)

Comment: They still looked at me strangely in Köln. I guess can probably butcher any language, no matter how flexible it is.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is correct in both grammar and meaning.
A peculiar charm is basically a charm that you can't place.
In other words, it has a charm, but you don't know why.
Peculiar means unusual.
You don't understand what the charm about it is, but it has something.
I doubt you've never had the feeling :)

Comment: Unless the question mark is the problem. It's out of place and context. But there's nothing wrong with the sentence itself. _Charm_ refers to the perception of (something about) a person as _charming_, and to the emotions of the perceiver as being _charmed_. It all happens in the perceiver's mind, but they can report the situation by referring to a specific feature, like something on her face.

Comment: Hmm I didn't expect the question mark to be part of it. It would be *Does it give her face a peculiar charm?*

Comment: That's got no problems, either. The speaker of the sentence is asking for an opinion from the addressee about the appearance of a third (female) person, having signalled by asking that the speaker may agree with the stated opinion, and that the speaker thinks it is possible that the addressee agrees as well.